# Как отфильтровать значение переменной в цикле?

Tags: php

Как отфильтровать по русскому алфавиту значения одной из нескольких переменной, которые выводятся через цикл foreach?

Comment: if($value!="значение"{ $newarr[]=$value}

Comment: Приведите пример кода, который у вас есть, вопрос не очень понятен.